Why is not result of rdd.getNumPartitions() equal to number of table`s partitions stored in hdfs?
In my task is necessary to get number of partitions of spark DataFrame. For this purpose I have tried to convert spark DataFrame to RDD and call getNumPartitions method. In case I read a table from HDFS and try to find out the number of its partitions by means of the way described above, obtained result is not equal to the number of table`s partitions stored in HDFS.
If the stored table contains large size partitions getNumPartitions method tends to return the value that is greater compared to the number of table`s partitions stored in HDFS and vice versa.
Why does this difference occur? Is there any way to find out an actual number of stored partitions?
For example, I deal with a table that contains 1_000_000 rows, 2 columns and the first column has 5 unique values.
import pandas as pd
import random

TABLE_LEN = 1_000_000
UNIQUE_ITEMS = 5
    
df = pd.DataFrame(
    data={
    "col_1" : [item for item in range(UNIQUE_ITEMS) for i in range(TABLE_LEN // UNIQUE_ITEMS)],
    "col_2" : [random.random() for _ in range(TABLE_LEN)]
    }
)

sdf = spark.createDataFrame(df)

Then I try to repartition table via two various ways for obtaining 5 partitions and write it to HDFS.
PARTITIONS_NUM = 5

sdf.repartition(PARTITIONS_NUM).write.mode("overwrite").saveAsTable(f"{db_name}.{tb_name}_1")

sdf.write.partitionBy("col_1").mode("overwrite").saveAsTable(f"{db_name}.{tb_name}_2")

Each of two cases demonstrates 5 written files.
Finally, I read these two tables in spark session and check the number of partitions.
table_1_partitions_num = spark.table(f"{db_name}.{tb_name}_1").rdd.getNumPartitions()
table_2_partitions_num = spark.table(f"{db_name}.{tb_name}_2").rdd.getNumPartitions()

print(table_1_partitions_num, table_2_partitions_num)

As result, numbers 2 and 3 are printed respectively.
If call getNumPartitions method before writing expected number is printed (5 partitions).
print(sdf.repartition(PARTITIONS_NUM).rdd.getNumPartitions()) 
